# DateType and various formats

Tags: html, date, symfony-forms, symfony

I have `DateType`. For example for saving foundation of some band to our database.

```
->add('founded', DateType::class, [
    'label' => 'Founded',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'required' => false
])
```

There is unknown **full date** sometimes. There can be only a **year and month** known, or just a **year** without the day and month. But if I fill an incomplete date to this HTML5 input, nothing is saved and I have HTML5 error.

How is it possible to parse full date, year and month or just year with DateType and HTML5 input? Or is there any other alternative and clean solution?

Comment: I imagine you are using `DateTime` for the value inside the model? How do you imagine it to be stored without the day and/or month? A simple and naive solution would be to use 3 fields, year, month and day (with the last 2 nullable). Probably a better solution would be to implement your own type

Comment: I had the same problem. I make separate fields for exact date (`DateTime` type) and year field (`integer` type). In form i used unmapped "combo" field where I can input known information (full date or year only) and used `DataTransormer` to parse this "combo" data correctly.I don't know is it good solution but it works in my case